# Need Some Help Getting a Regex to Work Correctly

Tags: regex

Using regex to convert a metar report into a readable format in bash and can't get one expression to work correctly. Here's the expression:

```
egrep -o '\s(SKC|FEW|SCT|BKN|OVC)[0-9]{3}\s' metar.txt | cut -c2-8
```

Here's the text file being read from:

```
METAR KBWI 211554Z 20012G15KT 10SM +RA TH FEW110 SCT140 BKN180 SKC300 OVC500 06
```

I'm going for FEW110, SCT140, BKN180, SKC300, and OVC500 but it only picks up FEW, BKN, and OVC but not SCT or SKC. I've tried writing the expression in different ways but none of them worked and would appreciate some assistance.
Currently this is the output I'm getting

```
FEW110
BKN180
OVC500
```

Comment: Bash what? `sed`, `awk`, `grep`, `perl`??

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this but it's using egrep, will edit that in

Comment: You should consider pasting the entire command.

Comment: You say you are 'converting' the file. Are you looking for a regex replacement? `grep` is the wrong tool for this...

Comment: Not really converting the file, just taking what's in it and printing it out in a more readable way

Comment: Please consider adding an example of desired output. your `grep` will only print a line with a match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\s` at the end is capturing the next item's beginning whitespace so it has to skip it, see https://regex101.com/r/ZGAeTW/1 to visualize the issue.

Change your regex to:

```
\b(SKC|FEW|SCT|BKN|OVC)[0-9]{3}\b
```

Comment: @nboz75 I saw your first comment saying it doesn't work. Did you have to do something special to get it working?

Comment: No I just accidently put the OVC as OVS so that messed it up but I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` to do this that replaces the `egrep` and `cut`:

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i ~ /^(SKC|FEW|SCT|BKN|OVC)[0-9]{3}$/) print $i}' metar.txt
FEW110
SCT140
BKN180
SKC300
OVC500
```